# Which jquery event to use?

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox, jquery

I've got a code like this to enable or disable som text inputs when a checkbox is marked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $("input:text").attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $("input:text").attr('disabled', false);
        }
      });
});
```

It seems to work when the user clicks on the checkbox, but the javascript can change the checkbox value by invoking:

```
$(":checkbox").attr('checked', true);
```

When the checkbox is changed by the javascript the event is not fired. I've tried with click() event but happens the same.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manually invoke the change event:

```
$(":checkbox").change();
```

Answer (score 4):

First, let's slim down that event handlers, since you're passing a boolean to [`.attr('disabled', bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and `.checked` is a boolean, let's take advantage of it, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function(){
    $("input:text").attr('disabled', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Then when changing the value programmatically just trigger the `change` event as well, like this:

```
$(":checkbox").attr('checked', true).change();
```

[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) without parameters is a shortcut for [`.trigger("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), which will cause your event handler to run.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm being too simplistic, but can't you let the JavaScript call the event manually whenever it changes the checkbox value?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to fire the event manually:

```
$(":checkbox").attr('checked', true);
$(":checkbox").change();
```

or

```
$(":checkbox").attr('checked', true).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `.trigger()` the `change event` manually:

```
$('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
```

You should never use a selector like `:checkbox`. It's an implicit usage of the universal `*` selector which will query all nodes on your site, which is pretty bad, which means it's pretty slow.

`input:checkbox` will still query all of your checkbox elements, you should us a `class` or an `id` to query for a specific element.

Ref.: [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why changing the checkbox through javascript doesn't fire the event.
But, i have a solution for this.

make

```
function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $("input:text").attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $("input:text").attr('disabled', false);
        }
      }
```

as a function.
Such as function cb_change_handler(){ ...}
and u can manually use this function when changing the value by javascript.